# How can I make `FusedResizeAndPadConv2D` run on GPUs (or configure `optimize_for_inference` not to fuse `resize` and `conv2d`)?

Tags: tensorflow

I have a graph which has a `resize` op before a `conv2d` op, and I find after calling `optimize_for_inference`, those two ops are fused as a `FusedResizeAndPadConv2D` op. I assume this is an optimization. However, I find the generated graph is super slow when I inference it. After some profiling, I find the `FusedResizeAndPadConv2D` is evaluated on CPUs (whereas in my original graph without `resize`, `conv2d` is evaluated with GPUs).

So I am wondering, how do I make my `FusedResizeAndPadConv2D` run on GPUs. Or, how do I configure `optimize_for_inference` to not fuse my `resize` and `conv2d`?

Answer (score 0):

According to this [doc](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/tools/graph_transforms#fuse_convolutions), `FusedResizeAndPadConv2D` is only generated for `ResizeBilinear`. Using `NEAREST_NEIGHBOR` as the resize method of `tf.image.resize_images` solved my issue.